# Cannot find reference 'midi' in '__init__.py'

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, midi

`Pygame.midi` is not recognized by PyCharm.
I have the pygame version 2.7 with Python 2.7
The IDLE seems to recognize it but PyCharm does not. Why is this?
I am trying to make a DRUM vst,
but I have not gotten far because the following error comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/POm/NewtonIncVST.py", line 12, in <module>
reading = in_port.midi.read()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'midi'
```

Code example

```
import pygame
import pygame.midi

pygame.init()
pygame.midi.init()

in_port = pygame.midi.get_default_input_id()

port = pygame.midi.get_default_output_id()

reading = in_port.pygame.midi.read()
check = reading.midi.poll()

pygame.midi.quit()
```

Can someone explain to me why PyCharm won't recognize `pygame.midi`?

Comment: You have to show some code. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `Pygame.Midi` requires portmidi which is preinstalled with pygame in the form of:

```
from pygame import pypm
pypm.Initialize()
#needed to initialize pygames compiled version of pyPortMidi
```

It seems to also be an issue other than the interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

It should be because your intrepeter isn't the same version as your IDLE version. For example, with an intrepeter of Python 2.7.5, it won't recognize that this code has any effect in the IDLE with a version 2.7.9:

**IDLE and PyCharm:**

```
string = 'XXXuuu'
string[:-3]
```

**Result:**

```
'XXX'
```

**PyCharm Result:**

```
#Nothing, says that `string[:-3]` has no effect in the program
```

So, this is an example of what happens when you have the wrong intrepeter. The other solution is to update our PyCharm to version 4.0.3 if your intrepeters are the same. If still not, file a bug report or test to see if your intrepeter is defective. I hope this helps you!